# Is there a way of creating a data/info sorting system across sheets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

So I am working on a Google Sheets project for a small business that I am going to be starting up. So I have Google sheet with 4 different sheets in it. Let me explain what each sheet is for:

1st sheet named "All Customers": This sheet will have a bunch of information about all the customers who are using our services (Name, Subject, Price, Location, Instructor).

The other 3 sheets are for the 3 instructors who would handle all the customers. The 3 instructors are Sam, Lucy, and Jason, and their Sheets are named Sam's Customers, Lucy's Customers, and Jason's Customers respectively.

I want a sorting system where I can put in the info of the customer in the "All customers" sheet and based on the instructor I assign to them, that customer's info gets sorted and appended into the assigned instructor's Sheet. SO here's an example:

*Jordan who wants to learn math needs to pay $200 for tutoring by us. He is located in NY so I assign him to our instructor Lucy who resides in NY and can tutor him.*

In this case, this is what the "All Customer" sheet would contain:

```
 A        B       C        D          E
```

1   `Name   Subject  Price   Location   Instructor`

2  `Jordan   Math     $200     NY        Lucy`

Now Based on the fact that Lucy was assigned as the instructor for Jordan, I want his select information to be added to the "Lucy's Customers" Sheet Like so:

```
  A        B       C
```

1 `Name    Price   Location`

2`Jordan    $200      NY`

That's what I'm trying to achieve. If Jordan was assigned Sam, the select information of Jordan would be added to the "Sam's Customer" sheet.

So I'd been at this for a while and based on my research I wasn't able to get anywhere. I was messing around with the following Formula: `=IF(INDIRECT("All Customers!C1:C")="Lucy",INDIRECT("All Customers!A2:A")," ")`

But I know this won't achieve what I'm doing.
Here is a link to the dummy spreadsheet for this project so anyone can mess around with it:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TGS9thgt77DSLbOUC5V2tRyjrDqE9He5ET17bM7HhZU/edit?usp=sharing

The Query method works but it only mirrors the information. I have pre-made cells in the instructors' sheets where there are cells that record if the customers under that specific instructor has paid or not monthly. The query is basically mirroring the information instead of copy/pasting. So when I get rid of a customer or switch the instructor in the main record, it will disappear from under the respective instructor's sheet. If that's the case then the corresponding cells that record the monthly payments in the instructor's sheet will be messed up.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I have introduced the queries in the sheet. Please have a look. The data can be retrieved using QUERY function of Google Sheets. example is given below

```
=QUERY('All Customers'!A:E,"SELECT A,C,D WHERE E CONTAINS 'Sam'",0).
```

Now, whenever you make new rows in "All Customers" sheet, data would automatically be updated in instructor sheet.

Hope it is clear.

Comment: Is there a way to store the data you get from the query function into the cells? Right now we use the formula and it basically mirrors the info from "All customers" to "Instructor's customers". Is there a way where it copies the info and pastes it instead?

Comment: Any specific reason you are looking to copy/paste the information instead of query function

Comment: The reason is I have pre-made cells in the other sheets where there are cells that record if the customers under that specific instructor have paid or not monthly. The query is basically mirroring the information instead of recording. So when I get rid of a customer or switch the instructor in the main record, it will disappear from under the first instructor's name. If that's the case then the corresponding cells that record the monthly payments in the first instructor's sheet will be messed up.